# sudden let-alist feature failure

Tags: debugging, emacs26

This morning, I wake up and restart my Emacs.app (26.3 GNU Emacs but the emacsformacosx.com version, from `brew cask`) and get stuck at this:

```
Eager macro-expansion failure: (error "Loading file /Users/erik/.emacs.d/elpa/let-alist-1.0.6/let-alist.elc failed to provide feature ‘let-alist’") [2 times]
```

The built-in version of `let-alist` was 1.0.5, upgraded to 1.0.6, to no avail.

Comment: Have a look into `/Users/erik/.emacs.d/elpa/let-alist-1.0.6/let-alist.el`. Is there a `(provide 'let-alist)` somewhere at the end of the file? If that is the case byte compile that file (see the menu items for byte compilation in the Elisp menu).

Comment: This sounds a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58565782/ht-elc-fails-to-provide-feature-ht#comment103462420_58569619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like somehow during an `Emacs.app` upgrade via brew cask (or possibly for other reasons), the `let-alist` providing source file at `~/.emacs.d/elpa/let-alist-1.0.6/let-alist.el` ended up as empty.

I fixed the issue by restoring its original/expected contents from http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/emacs-lisp/let-alist.el and restarting Emacs.

Thank you @Tobias, for pointing out the obvious — to start by looking up what's inside `let-alist.el`. :)

Comment: You should run `M-x package-install-file` on `let-alist.el` regardless of the apparent full functionality of the package. That corrects stuff like `autoloads` and so on.

Comment: FWIW, you can use `M-x package-reinstall` to reinstall the package, if your Emacs isn't functional, you can do it with Emacs -Q.

Comment: @xuchunyang Do **not** do that if you have already downloaded the file. `package-reinstall` deletes the package before installing it again. I for myself had a problem with downloads under WSL and had to download the stuff under Windows to install it in WSL. Only `package-install-file` works under such circumstances.

Comment: yes, sorry, just saw and deleted my comment.